# List all posts commented by current user

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, comments

I need a page to display all posts (in Foods custom post type) that have comments by the logged in user.

The list just needs to show the title with link to the title.

Is this possible?

What I've tried so far:

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>

<?php
        if ( is_user_logged_in()) {

        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $args=array(
            'post_type' => 'foods',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
        );
        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo 'Your Comments';
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        }
        wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
        }
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But of course I haven't used **$current_user->ID** yet. I'm not sure yet of how to use it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we want to avoid any filters and manual SQL queries, we could try (untested):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'foods',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post__in' => array_unique( 
         wp_list_pluck( 
            get_comments( array(
                'user_id' => get_current_user_id() 
                )
            ),       
            'comment_post_ID' 
         )
    ),
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Works like magic. I added array() in get_comments.

Comment: is there any way to get this for the liked posts via custom field? "Current User Liked Videos"

Comment: @Gazi it sounds like you are looking for the `meta_query` attribute in WP_Query if you need to search for posts with a given post meta (custom fields). See e.g. [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in the (old) Codex. Note that in general the meta queries might not scale well if you have many thousands of posts.

Comment: yea I know `'meta_key' =>'positive_like',` but I don't know how to integrate into your `array_unique(` section. I'm sorry for replying ona resolved topic but looks like the only one that can give the solution.

Comment: @Gazi I think there's still some info needed on the full detail to answer your question, but I would suggest to ask a new question, with all the details included, as the comment system here will prompt a warning on long comment conversation and maybe others would gain from such a question :-)

Comment: Thanks however I created another topic about this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321619/how-to-display-liked-posts-of-current-user-in-wordpress please if you find 2 minutes take a look maybe its something very easy for you but I lost all my day yesterday without any solution

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share additional behaviour related to @birgire answer.

With the current answer, in the event a user hasn't given any comments, `post__in` get a value of `0` which is blindly returning all posts.

To get around that, we should check if the `post__in` array is empty or not...

```
<?php

$post__in = wp_list_pluck( get_comments( array( 'user_id' => get_current_user_id() ) ),'comment_post_ID' );

if ( ! empty( $post__in ) ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'question',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__in' => array_unique( 
            wp_list_pluck(
                get_comments( array(
                        'user_id' => get_current_user_id() 
                    )
                ),       
                'comment_post_ID' 
            )
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    
        echo '<ul>';
        
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            
            $query->the_post();
            
            the_title( '<li>', '</li>' );
            
        };
    
        echo '</ul>';
            
    };

    wp_reset_postdata();
    
};
```

- @see [Why is WordPress showing query results from an empty post__in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23247671/3645650) for more information